# Google Cloud: what tool to use to split a request?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I would like to put something in front of my apps and Cloud Compute in Google Cloud, in a way that when a HTTP request comes in for any app URL's I can send another request to another APP somewhere and then move on with the original request of the user.

What is the tool in Google Cloud to achieve that?

Comment: to me it sounds like an internal application logic, not the cloud functionality

Comment: Usually, load balancers or firewall applications on premises have things like this. I don't know what would be the tool in Google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I must recommend to use [Splitting traffic across multiple versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/splitting-traffic#splitting_traffic_across_multiple_versions).

And also from Google Cloud CLI, you can try this command to split traffic across multiple version, example :

```
gcloud app services set-traffic [MY_SERVICE] --splits [MY_VERSION1]=[VERSION1_WEIGHT],[MY_VERSION2]=[VERSION2_WEIGHT] --split-by [IP_OR_COOKIE]
```

This is a best practice, if you have Dev environment and Production environment, Once a Dev environment is ready for production, you can manage splitting traffic for your Dev environment to go live in your production environment.